# How do I make sans serif superscript or subscript text in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, latex

I want to use a subscript in an axis label in a matplotlib figure. Using LaTeX I would set it as `$N_i$`, which gives me the italic serif font. I know I can get non-italic mathfont with `\mathrm`. But I would like to get the text in the default matplotlib sans-serif font so it matches the rest of the text in the figure. Is there a way to subscript text without using latex?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use `\mathregular` to use the font used for regular text outside of mathtext:

```
$\mathregular{N_i}$
```

Take a look [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html) for more information.

Answer (score 37):

You can do it by customizing `rcParams`. If you have multiple elements to customize, you can store them as a `dict` and the update the `rcParams':

```
params = {'mathtext.default': 'regular' }          
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```

If you want to do a single modification, you can simply type:

```
plt.rcParams.update({'mathtext.default':  'regular' })
```

In this respect, a trivial example would be as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1, 10, 40)
y = x**2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
params = {'mathtext.default': 'regular' }          
plt.rcParams.update(params)
ax.set_xlabel('$x_{my text}$')
ax.set_ylabel('$y_i$')
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can find more information on `RcParams` in the [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

Answer (score 3):

https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/mathtext.html

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y,'blue',label='$f(x)=e^{-x}$')
plt.plot(x,Mn3(x),'green',label='$M_{3}$')
plt.plot(x,Mn5(x),'red',label='$M_{5}$')
plt.plot(x,Mn7(x),'yellow',label='$M_{7}$')
plt.plot(x,Mn9(x),'pink',label='$M_{9}$')
plt.plot(x,Mn11(x),'black',label='$M_{11}$')
plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$y$')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A4Jb.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note that you've just answered an old question. We usually answer this kind of question if there has been any change in a relevant software version which caused a deprecation of the accepted answer's syntax.