# Subscript in matplotlib label *that is not italicized*?

Tags: matplotlib, latex, subscript

When I use r"$text_{sub}$" (or  "$text_{sub}$") the text is italicized.

I'd like all the text to be normal.

Here's a question asking about subscripts in general: [Subscripting text in matplotlib labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138464/subscripting-text-in-matplotlib-labels).

(But, again, I don't want the text in mathmode/italicized. I also tried to use \text and \textrm but that didn't work.)

Answer (score 0):

[How do I make sans serif superscript or subscript text in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698377/how-do-i-make-sans-serif-superscript-or-subscript-text-in-matplotlib)

```
params = {'mathtext.default': 'regular' }          
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```

@T-800 answer works perfectly for me.